# check if google event already exist in google calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I want to be able to verify if input date + hour is already created in google calendar.

This is the code I got but i'm stuck right now (Google quickstart tutorial). This code gives me the 10 upcoming events.

But What I would like is to be able to input a date, program then verify if event already exists before adding.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'], event['location'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:

I tried this code, but i'm getting an error.

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin="2020-04-22T10:00:00-00:00",
                                          timeMax="2020-04-22T12:00:00-00:00",
                                          singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('Event does not exist yet.')
    else:
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            if start == "2020-04-22T11:00:00-00:00":
                found = True
                print('Event has been found.')
                break
        if found != True:
            print('Event does not exist yet.')
```

ERROR im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cn/PycharmProjects/Calendrier/venv/quickstart.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/cn/PycharmProjects/Calendrier/venv/quickstart.py", line 56, in main
    if found != True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'found' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: From simple to complex, try to get them working separately, then combine. Can you retrieve data? Can you send data? On which basis do you want to compare? An id? Time, data? Name?

Comment: Do you only the start date and time of the event or also the end date and time?

Comment: Hi @Joe , for now, i can pull the data for a range but not for a specific date. I need to be able to input a date and time. and see if there's already a registered event in the calendar on inputed date. thank you for your help and sorry for my english!

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka I need the date + start time and end time !

Answer (score 0):

### Calendar API offers date specifying parameters `timeMin` and `timeMax`

[Description](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list):

`timeMax`:  Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to filter by.

`timeMin`:  Lower bound (exclusive) for an event's end time to filter by.

- Unfortunately those parameters do not allow you to directly find the exact date and time you are looking for, but you can use them to narrow down your result list as much as possible (knowing the event summary would also help significantly!).
- Once you have a list of all possible results, you need to loop through them and verify for each one either `event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))` is equal to the one you a looking for.

**Sample snippet**

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, 
                                        timeMax="Specify if possible",
                                        singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('Event does not exist yet.')
    else:
        found = False
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            if start == "SPECIFY HERE THE DATE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR":
                found = True
                print('Event has been found.')
                break
        if found != True:
            print('Event does not exist yet.')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply !  I will try this in the afternoon and let you know.

Comment: what is the date format I should use in `if start == '"SPECIFY HERE THE DATE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR": ' ` ?

Comment: I just updated my question, if u could take a look it would be appreciated.. thank you so much

Comment: The line `found = False` was missing in my sample, now it should work.

Comment: I added this line, but now i always get `"Event does not exist yet."`. I created an full day event the 21 and 22 april 2020. `timeMin="2020-04-22T10:00:00-00:00", timeMax="2020-04-22T12:00:00-00:00"`, `if start == "2020-04-22T11:00:00-00:00"`

Comment: Are you / do you create the events in UTC00:00? What happens if you log all found event start times after the line `start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))`? Also, are your events single events and repetitive? (in the latter case don't use `singleEvents=True`).

Comment: it's not working at all. it's fine, thank you for your time !!

Comment: If you can not log the start time of the events, apparently you do not have any events that fulfill the specified criteria. If your events are not created in your primary calendar - adapt the calendarId accordingly. I recommend you to test first with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) functionality for th method `Events: list`.First list all your events, and seeing that you obtain results, specify gradually more parameters to find the right ones you need for your query.  Once you know the paamters, implement them in Python.